# Android out of memory Bound Exception

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have images of 199KB which are stored in internal memory . Total Ram of my device is 512 MB. Android version is 2.3.5 . So what I am doing is that I am making all images on run time as Bit Map drawable.

I am getting following Exception:

```
10-10 14:16:03.782: E/dalvikvm-heap(20331): 73632-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-10 14:16:03.782: E/dalvikvm(20331): Out of memory: Heap Size=6599KB, Allocated=3949KB, Bitmap Size=13871KB, Limit=20480KB
10-10 14:16:03.782: E/dalvikvm(20331): Trim info: Footprint=6599KB, Allowed Footprint=6599KB, Trimmed=264KB
10-10 14:16:03.792: E/GraphicsJNI(20331): VM won't let us allocate 73632 bytes
```

Here is My Code:

```
File myDir =act.getApplicationContext().getDir(CURRENT_THEME, act.MODE_PRIVATE);
public BitmapDrawable getResourceFromInternalStorage(String resourceName)
 {
  // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    String filename = resourceName;
         File file = new File(myDir, filename+".png");
   Resources res = act.getResources();
   BitmapDrawable bd =null;
   bitmap=null;
   try
   {
//    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//    options.inSampleSize = 32;


              BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                   bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
                   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(),bmpFactoryOptions);

                   long reqsize=bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth*bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight*2;
                   long allocNativeHeap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();


                   final long heapPad=(long) Math.max(4*1024*1024,Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*0.1);
                   if ((reqsize + allocNativeHeap + heapPad) >= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())
                   {
                    Toast.makeText(act, "exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                      bitmap.recycle();
                  //  Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
//                    System.gc();
                    //  return null;

                   }
                   bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
                   bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(),bmpFactoryOptions);
          bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
   }
   catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e)
   {
    Log.v("Exceptional exception", e.getMessage());
    bitmap.recycle();
    System.gc();
   }
   finally{

   }

         return bd;
 }
```

Comment: I am getting same issue some days before but i solves it by allocating more ram size for emulator.

Comment: @BlueGreen I can't allocate more size for ram on device and my target is not emulator its the device

Answer (score 1):

Do recycle on your Bitmap. You are doing it but in catch block.

in try block:

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap=null;
```

Try above code and check.

Comment: I have already tried this but in try block bitmap is null. so there it throws exception on recycle.

Comment: Do one thing put condition like if(bitmap!=null{bitmap.recycle();bitmap=null;}

Comment: i am still getting an exception

Answer (score 0):

refer this tutorial on the android developers website

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

see:http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html